# Where can i download the iLOCOi2 mobile app source code?

Tags: java, iphone, android

i am a newbie for this kind of development. i am creating a mobile application which involves tracking, and where to download the source codes of iLOCi2 mobile application for my references. pls help me.

Comment: Maybe you should check this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2869338/where-to-start-to-learn-android

Comment: Please amend your question title to something that is meaningful and will help others identify potential answers to their own similar issues. (e.g "Where can i download the iLOCOi2 mobile app source code?")

Comment: iPhone?, Android?... Relax, Please rephrase your question with more details for which platform you are writing the App. Looking into the tags I could figure out you are for Android. Just confirm! :)

Comment: You should ask your self: "why my questions get always closed?" this is like this one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4922574/android-application-closed The title is not descriptive, the question is not clear (if there's a question), and no one cares if you are a newbie or not. Just ask clear questions and show what have you tried and expose what your problems are.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think its available for download.

Why not try this tutorial for using GPS? http://www.firstdroid.com/2010/04/29/android-development-using-gps-to-get-current-location-2/

Comment: Stackoverflow should be self contained - it would have taken you the same amount of time to copy/paste the URL of that site and to copy/paste the one-liner @gutentag asked for

Comment: Well its more than one line to solve it. And instead of copy and pasting the example it made sense to link to to its author's work so they can take credit.